# No matching service worker detected even though I have a service worker and no PWA icon

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, laravel-vue

i have try o convert laravel+vue.js to pwa. i have create manifest.json used workbox-cli for service worker. all install correctly but got error No matching service worker detected even though I have a service worker. below are my code

manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "stocky PWA",
    "short_name": "stocky PWA",
    "id":"/",
    "icons": [
        {
              "src": "/images/logo.png",
              "sizes": "192x192",
              "type": "image/png"
            }
    ],
    "start_url": "/",
    "scope": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#fff",
    "theme_color": "#000",
    "description": "You favorite recipe app",
    "dir": "ltr",
    "lang": "en-US"
}
```

I link the meta in harder

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel=icon href=/images/favicon.ico>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css">

    <title>Stocky | Ultimate Inventory With POS</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/public/manifest.json"/>
  </head>

  <body class="text-left">
    <noscript>
      <strong>
        We're sorry but Stocky doesn't work properly without JavaScript
        enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong
      >
    </noscript>

    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <div class="loading_wrap" id="loading_wrap">
      <div class="loader_logo">
      <img src="/images/logo.png" class="" alt="logo" />

      </div>

      <div class="loading"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <script src="/js/main.min.js?v=4.0.4">
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/public/sw.js', { scope: '/' }).then(function (registration) {
             // Registration was successful
             console.log('Signage Lab PWA: ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
            });
        })}
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

workbox-config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    globDirectory: 'public/',
    globPatterns: [
        '**/*.{css,js,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2,wav,ico,png,jpg,jpeg,gif,csv,php,json,txt,lock}'
    ],
    swDest: '/public/sw.js',
    ignoreURLParametersMatching: [
        /^utm_/,
        /^fbclid$/,
        
    ]
};
```

this error et I got

[image]

Comment: why 400 code snippets if 0 work?

Comment: sry i dontget u. can tell in details

Comment: i just wanted to say that code snippets in stack overflow questions should be used when necessary